# Scraping in Scrapy without pagination links

Tags: pagination, scrapy

I'm trying to paginate through a review site that doesn't have hyperlinked pagination buttons. Code snipit for pagination button:

```
<span data-page-number="2" data-offset="5" class="nav next taLnk " onclick="(ta.prwidgets.getjs(this,'handlers')).paginate(this); ta.trackEventOnPage('NORTH_STAR_PAGINATION', 'next', '2', 0);" data-page="LqWQeVsSVuWy3KkAoWMUKvKmmmmWxfWiEoWrGVQhIpMgQJIQxGCSsVEtSIgQfSIgWwGScJMVc2GSJQwVCCtgcsJCSJB"><div class="ui_button primary ">Next</div></span>
```

However there is pagination structure in the URL. For example `foobar.com/page1`

I'd like to avoid using a headless browser. Since I'm visiting many of these pages I can't manually inspect the page length of each one.

However, I do know there are 10 reviews per page and the review count is stated on the first page, as is the number of pages. Is there a way I can use this scraped information to paginate via url logic off of my initial start-url? Thanks!

(FYI Going to a url with a page count that doesn't exist redirects back to page 1)

Comment: can't you get `data-page-number` from `span` and use in place of `X` in `foobar.com/pageX` ?

Comment: you can generate list `start_urls` at start or uppend to this list later - directly `start_urls.uppend()` or using `Request()`